# How to transfer two values from controller to view, using ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I couldn't solve the following problem:

I send an ajax call to my controller and like to get two values back:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myController/myFunction",
        data: {
            sourceSubFunctionId: newSubFunctionId,
            destinationFunctionGroupId: FunctionGroupId
        },
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        error: function (Message) {
            log.error("Fehler beim Speichern der neuen Funktion.", Message);
            alert("Fehler beim Speichern der neuen Funktion.");
        },
        success: function (Message) {
            console.log(Message);
            newSubFunctionId = Message.SubFunctionId;
            newBMK = Message.BMK;
        }
    })
```

The action is triggered, so far ok.
Now I'd like to get the two values back. 
I thought Json is the right format for this so I created a simple json-like string:

```
 string result = "{ 'SubFunctionId': '215', 'BMK': 'myNewBMK' }";
```

This is the controller-action:

```
public JsonResult myFunction(int sourceSubFunctionId, int destinationFunctionGroupId)
    {
        string result = '{ "SubFunctionId": "215", "BMK": "MyNewBMK" }';
        //Also tried this:
        //result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

No matter what I do, even json throws an error for unexpexted sign or I get undefined in the result.

So simple question, How do I get two strings back for my controller to javascript?
It doesn't have to be a json-farmat, an array with two values would be fine.

Thanks Carsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're hitting the controller action correct?
If so here's what's happening;

What you're doing right now is you're simply returning a string and not a json object. Once you receive the string in your ajax, you might need to Serialize it to a json object so you could access its properties.

A quick fix is **instead of passing a string, you pass an anonymous object.**

Try the code below;

```
public JsonResult myFunction(int sourceSubFunctionId, int destinationFunctionGroupId)
{
   return Json(new {SubFunctionId="215",BMK="MyNewBMK"});
}
```